# JavaFX Update UI With Arrays With Loops Periodically

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I have a big Group. It has 10 Group and each Group has a rectangle and two text, one for name one for value. I have data for this 10 group from big to small. I have two arrays that store my data they have just 10 data. I want to show that data in UI with a loop then I will clear my arrays and I get new 10 data and I will show it in UI too. I can see changes on the console but it doesn't appear on UI. I can't control my arrays, code is running always without stopping and UI changes only when my data finished. How can I show my data periodically?

My Loop

```
            public Group allBars;

            while(bars.size()!=0){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                top10.add(bars.get(i));
                top10years.add(years.get(i));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < top10.size(); i++) {
                bars.remove(0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Group group = (Group) allBars.getChildren().get(i);
                Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) group.getChildren().get(0);
                Text value = (Text) group.getChildren().get(1);
                Text name = (Text) group.getChildren().get(2);
                rectangle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                value.setText(String.valueOf(top10.get(i).getValue()));
                name.setText(top10.get(i).getName());
                year.setText(top10years.get(i));
                System.out.println(year.getText()+" "+name.getText()+" "+value.getText());
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            }
            top10.clear();
            top10years.clear();
        }
```

My ScreenBuilder [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6H9k.png)

My UI [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dmF0.png)

My Console log

```
1500 Vijayanagar 500
1500 Cairo 400
1500 Hangzhou 250
1500 Tabriz 250
1500 Gauda 200
1500 Istanbul 200
1500 Paris 185
1500 Guangzhou 150
1500 Nanjing 147
<----------------->
1501 Beijing 672
1501 Vijayanagar 500
1501 Cairo 399
1501 Hangzhou 250
1501 Tabriz 248
1501 Istanbul 205
1501 Gauda 200
1501 Paris 186
1501 Guangzhou 150
1501 Nanjing 147
<----------------->
1502 Beijing 673
1502 Vijayanagar 499
1502 Cairo 398
1502 Hangzhou 250
1502 Tabriz 246
1502 Istanbul 210
...
```

**UPDATE**

I use Sedrick's codes. I didn't delete my arrays instead of it I give values to an AtomicInteger and I created a loop with these values.

```
 AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
        index.set(0);
        timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), (ActionEvent event) -> {
                    top10.get(counter.getAndIncrement());
                    for (int i = index.get(); i < index.get() + 10; i++) {
                        Group group = (Group) allBars.getChildren().get(i % 10);
                        Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) group.getChildren().get(0);
                        Text value = (Text) group.getChildren().get(1);
                        Text name = (Text) group.getChildren().get(2);
                        rectangle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                        value.setText(String.valueOf(top10.get(i).getValue()));
                        name.setText(top10.get(i).getName());
                        year.setText(top10years.get(i));
                        System.out.println(year.getText() + " " + name.getText() + " " + value.getText());
                        System.out.println("I-> " + i);
                    }
                    index.set(index.get() + 10);
                    System.out.println("Index -> " + index.get());
                    //top10.clear();
                    //top10years.clear();
                }));

        timeline.setCycleCount(bars.size());
        timeline.play();
```

Comment: A `loop` with `sleep` in it is most likely not the way to go. Try using `Timeline` or something else from the `Animation` API.

Comment: I tried Timeline sir but ı couldn't figure out problem. Can you show it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses `Timeline`. You can use `Timeline` in a loop-type way. Comments are in the code.

**Main**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author sedj601
 */
public class App extends Application
{

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        List<List<Bar>> barsList = readFileData();//Get data from file.
        
        //Create GUI Nodes.
        Label lblYear = new Label();
        List<Label> lblPlaces = new ArrayList();
        List<Label> lblDataPoints = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < barsList.get(0).size(); i++)
        {
            Label lblTempPlaces = new Label();
            lblPlaces.add(lblTempPlaces);
            
            Label lblTempDataPoints = new Label();
            lblDataPoints.add(lblTempDataPoints);
        }
        
        //Use Timeline to loop through the data and update the Labels.
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                 new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
                 List<Bar> currentBars = barsList.get(counter.getAndIncrement());
                 
                 for(int i = 0; i < currentBars.size(); i++)
                 {
                      lblPlaces.get(i).setText(currentBars.get(i).getPlace());
                      lblDataPoints.get(i).setText(Integer.toString(currentBars.get(i).getDataPoint()));
                      lblYear.setText(currentBars.get(i).getYear());                     
                 }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(barsList.size());
        timeline.play();
        
        //Add Nodes to Parent Nodes. Add Parent Nodes to the Scene
        VBox vbPlaces = new VBox();
        vbPlaces.getChildren().addAll(lblPlaces);
        VBox vbDataPoints = new VBox();
        vbDataPoints.getChildren().addAll(lblDataPoints);        
        HBox hBox = new HBox(vbPlaces, vbDataPoints);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(lblYear);
        root.setCenter(hBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    /**
     * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited JavaFX support.
     * Not needed for running from the command line.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    //Read the data from the file into a List of List<Bar>.
    public static List<List<Bar>> readFileData()
    {
        List<List<Bar>> barsList = new ArrayList();
        
        List<String> places = new ArrayList();
        places.add("Vijayanagar");
        places.add("Cairo");
        places.add("Hangzhou");
        places.add("Tabriz");
        places.add("Gauda");
        places.add("Istanbul");
        places.add("Paris");
        places.add("Guangzhou");
        places.add("Nanjing");
        
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList();
            for(int t = 0; t < places.size(); t++)
            {
                 bars.add(new Bar("150" + i, places.get(t), random.nextInt(700)));
            }
            Collections.sort(bars);
            barsList.add(bars);
        }
                
        return barsList;
    }
}
```

**Bar**

```
/**
 *
 * @author sedrick
 */
public class Bar implements Comparable<Bar>{
    private String year;
    private String place;
    private Integer dataPoint;

    public Bar(String year, String place, Integer dataPoint) {
        this.year = year;
        this.place = place;
        this.dataPoint = dataPoint;
    }

    public Integer getDataPoint() {
        return dataPoint;
    }

    public void setDataPoint(Integer dataPoint) {
        this.dataPoint = dataPoint;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Bar{year=").append(year);
        sb.append(", place=").append(place);
        sb.append(", dataPoint=").append(dataPoint);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }    
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Bar bar)
    {        
        return bar.getDataPoint().compareTo(this.getDataPoint());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer. I updated some code and now working fine sir.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're making the FX Application Thread constantly busy while you're reading you data and updating display. This thread is responsible for drawing your scene and notifying your application with input events. By making it busy for 5 seconds, you're rendering your application unresponsive for that amount of time.

There's a number of ways in which you can wait or do stuff in the background, and only come back to the FX Application Thread for FX related things such as updating your UI.

I'll show you a few examples below, with a simple task that updates a `Label` every 500ms with the current date and time. Not your program, but very close to it in its requirements.

`enableButtons(boolean)` is just a dummy method call to illustrate where you're supposed to setup your before/after animation display. In my test, I was disabling the buttons that triggered the animation, and re-enabling them afterwards. I've commented out these calls.

1. Use Animation API. For instance, with a `PauseTransition`

```java
private void withPauseAnimation() {
  //enableButtons(false);
  DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
  PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(500));
  pause.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    int index = 0;
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
      String disp = fmt.format(LocalDateTime.now());
      System.out.println(disp);
      label.setText(disp);
      if (stage.isShowing() && ++index < 10) {
        pause.play();
      } else {
        //enableButtons(true);
      }
    }
  });
  pause.play();
}
```

*cons: somewhat awkward program structure, and granularity of one animation frame (60fps = 17ms)*

2. Use `java.util.concurrent` API. Here, a `ScheduledExecutorService`

```java
private void withExecutor() {
  //enableButtons(false);
  DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
  ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    int index = 0;
    public void run() {
      if (stage.isShowing()) {
        String disp = fmt.format(LocalDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(disp);
        Platform.runLater(() -> label.setText(disp));
        if (++index >= 10) {
          exec.shutdownNow();
          //Platform.runLater(() -> enableButtons(true));
        }
      } else {
        exec.shutdownNow();
      }
    }
  }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

*cons: Need to use `Platform.runLater` to make display updates or any FX stuff. Don't forget to shutdown the `Executor` before closing your application, or it will prevent your process from terminating*

3. Use `javafx.concurrent` API. Here, a `ScheduledService`

```java
private class BarsService extends ScheduledService<Void> {
  
  private int index = -1;
  DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
  
  public BarsService() {
    super();
    setDelay(Duration.ZERO);
    setPeriod(Duration.millis(500));
  }
  
  @Override
  public void start() {
    //enableButtons(false);
    super.start();
  }
  
  @Override
  protected Task<Void> createTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {
      @Override
      protected Void call() throws Exception {
        index++;
        //You're supposed to do background work here, but we only need to increment our counter
        return null;
      }
    };
  }
  
  @Override
  protected void succeeded() {
    super.succeeded();
    String disp = fmt.format(LocalDateTime.now());
    System.out.println(disp);
    label.setText(disp);
    if (index >= 9) {
      super.cancel();
      //enableButtons(true);
    }
  }
  
  @Override
  protected void failed() {
    super.failed();
    getException().printStackTrace();
    //enableButtons(true);
  }
  
}
```

And to start the animation:

```java
new BarsService().start();
```

*cons: very verbose code for such a small task*

Comment: Just edited the first 2 examples to make them index-based instead of time-based

Comment: Thank you so much julien.giband. I tried your code too but I couldn't run it properly because I'm new at JavaFX. Sedrick's method is working fine too.